# MGLSymbolStyleLayer "iconRotation" animation

Tags: swift, mapbox, mapbox-ios

is it possible to animate my marker rotation using MGLSymbolStyleLayer's iconRotation property ? or is there any other way to rotate my marker smoothly ?
I just want to rotate my marker smoothly , as of now the rotation is fine but it is quite snappy. Also i get different bearing for different markers from the server, is there any way i can rotate my marker using MGLPointAnnotation only ?. My use case is that i want different degree rotation for different markers (each of same icon)

```
let point = MGLPointAnnotation()
    point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 30.699335, longitude: 76.836422)
    let shapeSource = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "marker-source", shape: point, options: nil)
    shapeLayer = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: "marker-style", source: shapeSource)
    if let image = UIImage(named: "auto") {
        mapView.style?.setImage(image, forName: "auto")
    }
    shapeLayer?.iconImageName = NSExpression(forConstantValue: "auto")
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(3.0)
        self.shapeLayer?.iconRotation = NSExpression(forConstantValue: 120.0)
        CATransaction.commit()
```

Comment: Please explain what you code is trying to do, and what happens instead.

Comment: You need to include all that info in the question, not as a comment. Please edit your question such that a future potential reader can understand exactly what you ask, and can apply any possible answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can animate an MGLSymbolStyleLayer using the [add live data example](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/live-data/). You would need to set your @objc function to layer.iconRotation and have that value change every time the function is executed. You can also do the same using an MGLPointFeature or MGLPointAnnotation as a source for an MGLSymbolStyleLayer. Please take a look at the Mapbox Add markers and shapes documentation [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/overview/markers-and-annotations/) to see the different features that are supported.